# Compare two arrays with not the same order

Tags: java, arrays, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm new in coding and I decided to learn java, groovy. I am making a simple exercise. I got a two array and I must compare them if they are equal. I take values from 2 database and these databases are same, but values are not in the same order, but they are equal. For example, I have:

```
ArrayList collection1 = ["test","a"]
ArrayList collection2 = ["a","test"]
```

Well I tried this:

```
assert collection1.equals(collection2)
```

But I know that this works only when values in those arrays are placed in same order.

Comment: You could always sort the arrays and then compare them.

Comment: `assert collection1.size() == collection2.size() && collection1.containsAll(collection2)`

Comment: What types of values are being stored in the arrays? Strings? Int primitives?  Integers objects?  Lists?  Complex object graphs?  This could be as simple as sorting the two arrays before comparing, or as complex as implementing custom Comparators, depending on the what type of data you're working with.

Comment: Well, normally the order is a property that affects array/list equality as well. Why don't you read the data ordered by some criteria? If only the elements are relevant use a `Set` instead of an array.

Comment: @Lino can you post it as an answer, so I can accept it as an answer? It very well for me !

Comment: @MrSamuelSmith [I already did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711315/5515060)

Comment: @Speed Not a duplicate. The other question refers to Javascript. This relates to Groovy or Java

Comment: @AdrianRM My 4-year-old bad!

Comment: @Speed. Nope. Only 7 months old. ;D And because you deleted your comment, now these comments remain without context :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two methods:

1. Check that they are equal sizes
2. Wrap the two arrays with `Arrays.asList()`
3. Check if `a` contains all elements from `b`

```
public static boolean equals(Object[] a, Object[] b) {
    return a.length == b.length && Array.asList(a).containsAll(Arrays.asList(b));
}
```

Another way would be to just iterate over both arrays at once and then check if the elements are equal:

```
public static boolean equals(Object[] a, Object[] b) {
    if(a.length != b.length) return false;
    outer: for(Object aObject : a) {
         for(Object bObject : b) {
              if(a.equals(b)) continue outer;
         }
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Both methods are rather fast, the first introduces an additional wrapper around the arrays, but is neglectable as `Arrays.asList()` just uses the given array as a View and does not do any additional copying.

---

Now it seems that you're actually comparing two `Collection`s, then you can just use this approach:

```
public static boolean equals(Collection<?> a, Collection<?> b) {
     return a.size() == b.size() && a.containsAll(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an array the order is important. If you want an array without checking the order, you should use Sets [Sets tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-in-java/).

However, if you don't want to use another type I suggest you implement your own function that checks the presence of each element in one another.

I hope this can helps !

Answer (score 0):

I know absolutely zilch about Java programming, but I've thought of this problem more generally for some time and I think I have a workable solution that is generalizable if you know *a priori* all the values that can be contained in the array.

If you assign a prime number to each possible string that can be in the array and then multiply all the elements of an array together, then the multiplied number will represent a unique combination, but not order, or the elements of the array. To close the loop, then you just have to compare the values of that multiplication. If there's a better answer, use that, but I thought I would share this idea.

Comment: I don't know why but this makes me smile for a while.

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy, just sort them, and check the sorted lists:

```
assert listA.sort(false) == listB.sort(false)
```

Or if they can't have duplicates, use Sets as suggested by [@Baldwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711311/6509)